# Play .bag file from .launch error

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

when i try to play a bag-file from a .launch file i get the follwing error:

```
started core service [/rosout]
process[player-2]: started with pid [3743]
[ INFO] [1566472363.629640670]: Opening ~/Schreibtisch/ros_workspace/kitti_2011_09_26_drive_0002_synced.bag
[FATAL] [1566472363.649632374]: Error opening file: ~/Schreibtisch/ros_workspace/kitti_2011_09_26_drive_0002_synced.bag
[player-2] process has died [pid 3743, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/rosbag/play ~/Schreibtisch/ros_workspace/kitti_2011_09_26_drive_0002_synced.bag __name:=player __log:=/home/bryan/.ros/log/c2eb5e16-c4cd-11e9-ac1b-632677946da6/player-2.log].
log file: /home/bryan/.ros/log/c2eb5e16-c4cd-11e9-ac1b-632677946da6/player-2*.log
[ERROR] [1566477676.826236486]: poll failed with error Interrupted system call
```

my launch file looks quite simple:

```
<launch>

  <!-- Start Bag File -->
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="player" output="screen" args="~/Schreibtisch/ros_workspace/kitti_2011_09_26_drive_0002_synced.bag"/>

</launch>
```

Schreibtisch = Desktop..

What is the Problem?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331346/play-.bag-file-from-.launch-error/) by [Horst](https://answers.ros.org/users/44887/horst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2019-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What is the Problem?
>
> [..]
>
> ```
> <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="player" output="screen" args="~/Schreibtisch/ros_workspace/kitti_2011_09_26_drive_0002_synced.bag"/>
> ```

The problem is that `~` is something that is evaluated (ie: replaced) by your shell, not by `roslaunch`.

And `roslaunch` starts `rosbag` directly, without asking `bash` (most likely your shell) to first resolve the path. So `rosbag` is literally passed `~/Schreibtisch/ros_workspace/..`, which it cannot open as it is not a valid path.

You cannot use `~` in a path in a `.launch` file.

You must either use an absolute path, or a relative path that is relative to a ROS package or relative to some environment variable. For the latter, you could perhaps use `$HOME`, in combination with the `$(env ..)` substitution arg ([documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args)).

On Melodic you could also perhaps use `$(dirname)`, which will return the absolute path to the directory the `.launch` file itself is stored in.

---

Note that the use of relative paths can lead to some unexpected behaviour if you're not careful. See #q235337 for some related Q&As.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Horst](https://answers.ros.org/users/44887/horst/) on 2019-08-22**:
thanks it worked with $(dirname), but why "home/bryan/Schreibtisch/ros_workspace/kitti_2011_09_26_drive_0002_synced.bag" won't work? I think that is a absolute path..?

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2019-08-22**:
"/home/bryan/Schreibtisch/ros_workspace/kitti_2011_09_26_drive_0002_synced.bag"

would probably work, notice the `/` at the beginning.